# extendRoutes not accepting the dynamic urls

Tags: redirect, routes, dynamic-routing, nuxtjs2, nuxt.config.js

I have a url in nuxt app
[https://example.netlify.app/nl/appartementen/strand?experiences_in[]=strand&types_in[]=appartementen](https://example.netlify.app/nl/appartementen/strand?experiences_in%5B%5D=strand&types_in%5B%5D=appartementen)

In which appartementen is a type & strand is an experience.
I write the extended routes code like that

```
routes.push({
        name: 'AccommodationIndex',
        path: '/:type?/:experience?',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/accommodations/index.vue'),
      });
```

It's not working!

But If I use this route for single query params like this type of url like
https://example.netlify.app/nl/kindvriendelijk?experiences_in%5B%5D=kindvriendelijk

```
routes.push({
        name: 'AccommodationIndex',
        path: '/:experience',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/accommodations/index.vue'),
      });
```

This is working.
I am writing that code in the `nuxt.config.js` in extended routes.